# How to do lots of 301 Redirect (Tomcat) with complete urls

Tags: java, .htaccess, tomcat, redirect, filter

I have several websites running on a single tomcat instance, and at application level the cms reads the domain and it is smart enough to show the right website to the user.
For example I have www.firstwebsite.com/welcome and the cms shows the homepage for  firstwebsite, while when it receives requests with the domain www.secondwebsite.com/welcome the cms shows the welcome page for secondwebsite.
But both websites has just replaced two old website with different url structure, for example the old www.firstwebsite.com/my-product-in-old-website should redirect (301) to the page www.firstwebsite.com/my-product-in-new-website.

 
The same happens for secondwebsite. 
Please note that the redirect is not based by path, but it is also based on the domain name, i.e. if I define a redirect for /my-product-in-old-website the redirect is sent for both websites instead of only for firstwebsite.

Is there anything that allows me to do 301 redirect based on the full url of the request (website domain included)?

**EDIT** 
New and old urls does not follow a particular pattern so for example firstwebsite.com/something/something/my-old-page -> firstwebsite.com/something-else/my-new-page

firstwebsite.com/my-old-page2 -> firstwebsite.com/something/something/my-new-page2

and 

secondwebsite.com/somethingelse/somethingelse/my-old-page -> secondwebsite.com/somethingelse-xyz/my-new-page

secondwebsite.com/my-old-pageXYZ -> secondwebsite.com/something/something/my-new-page-ABC

Comment: you may use .htaccess becouse RewriteCond deals with full request url including domen

Comment: can you explain it well in an answer then?

Comment: Describe a little more detail the structure of the old and new urls for 1st and 2nd domens.

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: Sorry, Daniele.  I don't understand. You sad "I cannot use something like htaccess because the redirect is not based by path", but all examples  are the same replaces for both domains

Comment: edited the post again (description and examples), having a look to htaccess, and it might suit

Comment: To don't extended discussions :) i say some words. You can use RewriteCond which tests domain and next RwriteRule will run only when  RewriteCond condition true. So, you can write rules for different domain separately. But in your case you should write rule for every path, unfortunatly. But, if there are the same redirects, you can write its once

Comment: Ok, can you show me how you would implement the examples above with htaccess?